# How to paint a location icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, icons, flutter-custompainter

I am trying to paint a icon with green color. I am using custom painter class.

Sample code:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
  List<Offset> mark = [];

  void updatePosition(TapDownDetails details) {
    x = details.localPosition.dx;
    y = details.localPosition.dy;
    setState(() {
      mark.add(Offset(x, y));
      print("mark:$mark");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: updatePosition,
          child: RepaintBoundary(
              child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
            height: 300,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/dark.jpg',
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: MyCustomPainter(mark),
            ),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Offset> marks;
  const MyCustomPainter(this.marks);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 15.0;

    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, marks, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

It's helped me to draw a points list. How can I draw a list of location icon instead of green points?

Comment: IconData is a font, so your real question is how to draw text using custompainter.

Comment: @Alex Rintt okay then how to draw a multiple text using cistompainter